# How to use Gutenberg in CMB2?

Tags: metabox

I am not able to get the Gutenberg editor in CMB2 ([repo](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/tree/v2.6.0)). I have follow the comment mentioned on the [example file](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/blob/008d9b83263d971d6bd41c27e31113db852d5ef3/example-functions.php#L138-L147) but not working.

I have set the `'mb_callback_args' => [ '__block_editor_compatible_meta_box' => true ]` but doesn't make any difference.

```
$cmb = new_cmb2_box( [
    'id'               => 'book_item_meta_box',
    'title'            => __( 'Book Data Section', 'booker' ),
    'object_types'     => [ 'book', ],
    'context'          => 'normal',
    'priority'         => 'high',
    'show_names'       => true,
    'mb_callback_args' => [ '__block_editor_compatible_meta_box' => true ],     
] );
```

Any help please?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the Gutenberg editor in CMB2"? Do you want to add your custom field _to_ Gutenberg? Or are you trying to use Gutenberg _as_ a field?

Comment: I want Gutenberg use as metabox. CMB2 allow to use metabox type `WYSIWYG` but I am trying to use `Gutenberg` instead. I have read their docs and try to get it but nothing works.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. This is probably why there's nothing in their docs about it. Regardless, questions about 3rd-party plugins should be directed to their developers.

Comment: Hmm. so is there any way where I can implement or customize to get the `Gutenberg` editor in custom metabox?

Answer (score 1):

This is, at least at the moment, not possible. You can use CMB2 Meta Boxes in Gutenberg Post Types, but you can not make a CMB2 Field where you can use Gutenberg - as of now.

However, as the Gutenberg Editor is developed further, a CMB2 Block-Editor-Field is not that far. As of now, you can already integrate the Block Editor on your own admin page (see https://github.com/getdave/standalone-block-editor for instance).

So, if you only need a settings page with a Block Editor, you could use this. You could also try and implement this code into a custom CMB2 Field (I'm not sure this is possible at the moment).

Happy Coding!